# How to focus an MDL TextField

Tags: material-design-lite

What is the proper way to focus a material design lite TextField?

This works:

```
$("#myTextField").focus();
```

This does not work:

```
document.getElementById('myTextField').parentNode.MaterialTextfield.focus();
```

However, this very similar code works to disable a TextField:

```
document.getElementById('myTextField').parentNode.MaterialTextfield.disable();
```

Comment: I don't think there is an MDL method to set focus. Your first example is the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery.

```
  input.focus();
  input.parentNode.classList.add('is-dirty');
```

Comment: is-dirty will permanently float the label - use "is-focused" instead to just float it whilst the input has focus.